# Transforming image "vibrating" horribly in Firefox. Why?

Tags: css, firefox, css-transitions, css-transforms

This is related to a question I asked previously but I didn't really find the source of my problem until just now.

What I want is a circle that expands to a rectangle.  It also scales from .9 to 1.

What I have is this http://codepen.io/StuffieStephie/full/zrZwEQ/ I've slowed down the animation so the "vibration" is clearer.

```
    #seasonOne .test {
    padding:0;
        background-color: #fff;
    background: #fff url('http://i296.photobucket.com/albums/mm174/StuffieStephie/S1ChibiPreview2_zpsswyamase.png') 50% 50% no-repeat;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transition: 2s;
            -moz-transition: 2s;
            transition: 2s;
    -webkit-transform: scale(.9);
        -ms-transform: scale(.9);
        -moz-transform: scale(.9);
            transform: scale(.9);
    font-size: 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
            transform-origin: 50% 50%;

}

#seasonOne:hover .test {
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
     -moz-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;

    border-radius: 0;
}
```

[image: It vibrates about its origin]

Why is it shaking like this and only in Firefox? Adding vendor prefixes does not help...

Comment: Okay so firstly `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA`. With that out of the way it seems to be related to how Firefox handles readjusting the margins, as removing the auto on the image's left-right margin reduced the vibration significantly. Since you have a fixed width, you might be able to manually correct the margins and not have a right-margin that needs growing (ie, make the image div `position:relative` and center it yourself via `left:__px`. Gimme a moment...

Comment: oh also the vendor prefixes won't help if you put them above the rule they're the prefix of- the prefixed version gets overridden by the standards version, both internal to the browser and internal to the CSS if the browser knows what the standards version is.

Comment: Alright so my idea didn't work. I can tell you the problem is for sure actually related to the width scaling. Disable *that* and all the stuttering goes away. My copy of Chrome also stutters, but not to the same degree- making me think Firefox's problem is that it's actually forcing every frame rather than allowing some skipping. I'll play with this for another 10-15 minutes, let you know if I find something. Nice find.

Comment: @abluejelly Eeey, thanks for looking into this!  It's a shame that it's the width scaling...  Going from the circle preview to the full width was the whole appeal of the effect D: Also, I think removing the scale helps too, but it seems to still shake a little even with it off.

Comment: @abluejelly If it can't be solved I'll just deal with it.  The animation will be .3s normally and it's not that pronounced when it's that quick. But holy guacamole, she shakes like an elderly chihuahua at slower speeds D: This has been driving my crazy all day! I've still gotta handle all the AJAX stuff once the read more has been clicked... curse my OCD :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the cause is pretty much the background image. All browsers stutter a bit when they're trying to animate both size and position in two directions, it's just Firefox was dropping the least amount of frames <sup>(shots fired?)</sup>. It's hard to animate smoothly without knowing that's exactly what you're animating (reason js libraries like GSAP are as great as they are). Thus, what you want to do is either **a)** only do one at a time or **b)** "Fake" it by animating only size on the image itself, and push the rest of the animation onto a frame around the image.

Because the image is centered, we can totally do B:

```css
.season img {
  float: left;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  animation-delay:0.1s; 
}

.season p.oneP {
  animation-delay:0.5s; 
}

.season p.twoP {
  animation-delay:0.75s; 
}
.season p.threeP {
  animation-delay:1s; 
}
.season h2 {
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-top: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.season .smallText {
  animation-delay:0.2s; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
.season h6, .season .arts, .season h3 {
  text-align: center !important;
  animation-delay: 1.8s;
}
.next, .prev {
  float: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 49%;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  border: 3px solid #EEE;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.prev {
  float: left;
}
.prev img.preview, .next img.preview {
  float: left;
}
.previews {
  display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around; /* Safari 6.1+ */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.card{
  color: #ff2772;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 3px 1px;
  background-color: #2d3034;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: .25s;
  cursor:pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ff2772;
  text-align: center;
}
.floatRight {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;

}
#page-content .card h6 {
  padding: 10px 2px;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  transition: .3s;

  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}


#page-content .card .smallText {
  transition: .3s;
  background: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}

#page-content .card:hover .smallText, #page-content .card:hover h6{
  background-color: #ff2772;
  color: #2d3034;
}
.card:hover{
  background: #fff;
}

/*
.card img {
width: 200px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 100%;
background: #fff;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
transform: scale(.9);
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
/*.card .test {
transform: scale(.9);
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
overflow-x: hidden;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}
*/




.imgwrapper {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#seasonOne .test {
  padding:0;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color: #2d3034;
  border-width:80px;
  display: block;
  transition:all 2s, border-color 0.25s;
  transform: scale(.9);
  font-size: 0;  
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top:-80px;
  left:-30px;
}
#seasonOne .img{
  background: #fff url('http://i296.photobucket.com/albums/mm174/StuffieStephie/S1ChibiPreview2_zpsswyamase.png') 50% 50% no-repeat;
  /*Was gonna make that a dataURI, but that's 112KB. Heh.*/
  width:250px;
  height:200px;
  transition: 2s;
  transform: scale(.9);
  position:absolute;
  left:25px;
}

#seasonOne:hover .test {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: scale(1);
  border-radius: 0;
  border-color:#fff;
  left:-55px;
}
#seasonOne:hover .img{
  transform: scale(1);
}



.card:hover img{
  transform: scale(1);
  border-radius: 0;
}


hr {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
img.preview {
  transform: scale(.9);
  width: 200px;
  display: inline;
  float: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}
.art img.preview:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.art img.preview:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 2.25s;
}

.logo{
  clear:left;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
img.preview:hover {
  transform: scale(1);
  box-shadow: 0 15px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-radius: 0;
}
.season img.no-float {
  float: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .season h6 {
    clear: both;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) { 
  .prev img.preview, .next img.preview {
    float: left;
  }

  .season p {
    clear: both;
  }
  .prev p, .next p {
    clear: none;
  }
  .season img{
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) { 
  .card {
    /*width: 49%;/*For this part to work, you'll have to do up more rules
     *, otherwise you'll get an off-center image.*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

  .prev, .next{
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
    margin: 5px auto;
  }
  .prev img.preview, .next img.preview {
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 399px) {
  .card{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Meta -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,width=device-width,user-scalable=no" />
        <!-- Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/animatecss/2.1.0/animate.min.css">
        <!-- Magnific Popup core CSS file -->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:700|Montserrat:700|Open+Sans|Sniglet:400,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kamicon.net/assets/styles/mainStyles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" 
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="site-canvas">
            <div id="page-content">
                <section>
                    <h1>Help Me!</h1>
                    <p>The art shakes horribly when you hover over it in Firefox Why!?</p>
                    <div id="area" class="holder"></div>
                    <div class="previews">
                        <div id="seasonOne" class="card seasonOne">
                            <h6 class="center">Season 1 (2009) - The Pilot</h6>
                            <div class="imgwrapper">
                                <div class="img"></div>
                                <div class="test"></div>
                                <div class="wrapper2"></div>
                            </div>
                            <p class="animated smallText fadeInRight oneP">Ut cursus purus in lacinia tincidunt. Quisque lorem odio, posuere ut aliquam vel, fringilla at enim. Duis ligula lacus, viverra et sapien rhoncus, commodo euismod ipsum.</p>
                            <a href="#area" class="button">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr/>
                </section>
            </div>
            <!-- #page-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- #site-canvas -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively on [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoWEww?editors=010).

I separated the frame (`.test` still) and the image (`.img`), contained both in a wrapper (`.imgwrapper`).

The wrapper handles the footprint in the page layout.

The frame has its border-color now animated specially with the background of the card, as well as is positioned (and `border-width`'d) fairly hackishly.... take a look at how I did it and you'll see what I mean. Heh.

The picture now has fixed width and position, only animating scale (hence, no longer stuttering).

I'm like 90% sure there's a better way to do this, but because I had to absolute-position the image (so its position wouldn't twitch while the frame's did) I couldn't keep the image-div as a child of the frame-div.

Also, I'm surprised it's as awkward as it is to generate a square with rounded inner corners. I basically just made a really thick circle and said "only show this square of it".

EDIT NOTE: the resizing for `@media` width below `750px` caused an offcenter. Disabling it "fixed" it. Only noticed when I moved the fixed code here, heh.

Comment: You're a champ dude! I really appreciate you staying on it.  And I will admit I'm not a fan of empty divs (ideally I'd have an img tag in there rather than setting the source through css but eh). It is hackish, but the results are nice, and it looks cute, which is what I wanted. So thank you so much!

Comment: @StephanieQ no prob. My ego struck and couldn't put it down until I emerged triumphant haha. You'd be surprised how often that gets me through weird bugs >.>